# How to rename service function of httpFunction interface?

Tags: java, interface, google-cloud-functions

I am writing a java google cloud function that implements HttpFunction. HttpFunction is an interface and has service function which takes in HttpRequest and HttpResponse. In my class I have to override service to call the HttpFunction. Is there a way to rename this from service to any other name?
I don't think it is possible from what I have learnt but wanted to know if there is way that I might not know of.

```
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction; 
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest; 
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse; 

public class MyFunction implements HttpFunction { 
  @Override public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws IOException { 
  } 
}
```

I want service to be rename to say inputProcess

```
public class MyFunction implements HttpFunction { 
  @Override public void inputProcess(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws IOException { 
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpFunction` interface defines a method called `service`.  You are 100% obliged to implement exactly the name of that method in order to satisfy the compiler, if you want to implement the interface. There are no workarounds to this - just use the name of the method as it requires.

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpFunction;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpRequest;
import com.google.cloud.functions.HttpResponse;

public class MyFunction implements HttpFunction {
    @Override
    public void service(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        inputProcess(request, response);
    }
    
    public void inputProcess(HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        // Your implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to rename the `service` method in the `HttpFunction` interface.

The method name is part of the interface contract and must be implemented with the exact same signature and name.

If you need to use a different name for your method, you would have to create a separate method with the desired name and then delegate the logic to it from the `service` method.

However, note that the `service` method itself must still be implemented and called as required by the interface.